# finding duplicate rows with different IDs based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, teradata

please forgive me if my jargon is off. I'm still learning!

I just started using Teradata, and to be honest has been a lot of fun. however, I have hit a road block that has stumped me for a while.

I successfully selected a table from a database that looks like:

```
ID      service      date    name
```

```
1       service1    1/5/15   john      
2       service2    1/7/15   steve
3       service3    1/8/15   lola
4       service4    1/3/15   joan
5       service5    1/5/15   fred         
6       service3    1/3/15   joan
7       service5    1/8/15   oscar
```

Now I want to search the data base again to find any duplicate IDs (example: to see if service service1 with date 1/5/15 with name john exists on another row with a different ID.)

At first, I did something like this:

```
SELECT ID, service, date, name
FROM table
WHERE table.service = ANY(service1, service2, service3, service4, service5, service3, service5)
AND table.date = ANY('1/5/15', '1/7/15, '1/8/15', '1/3/15', '1/5/15',  '1/3/15',  '1/8/15')
AND table.name = ANY('john', 'steve', 'lola', 'joan', 'fred', 'joan', 'oscar');
```

But this is giving me more rows than I wanted.

example:

```
ID       service     date     name
92       service3    1/8/15   steve
```

is of no use to me since I am looking for IDs that have the same combination of service, date, and name as of any of the other IDs in the above table.

something like this would be favorable:

```
ID       service     date     name
609      service3    1/8/15   lola
```

since it matches than of ID 3.

I was curious to see if it were possible to treat the three columns (service, date, name) as a vector and maybe select the rows that match it that way?

ex

```
......
WHERE (table.service, table.date, table.name) = ANY((service3,1/8/15,lola), (service1, 1/5/15, john), ...etc)
```

My Teradata is down right now, So I have yet to try the above example. Nevertheless, any thoughts/feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Whence is the ID value of `609` in your expected output?

Comment: The above table isn't my actual table; it was made to look like it so I didn't give out any confidential information. But either way these duplicates I am looking for are a small subset of a very large amount of rows; I don't know how many rows, I just know that I couldn't load them

Comment: I gave you an answer below, give it a try and if it doesn't work then leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The following query may be what you are trying to achieve.  This selects IDs for which the combination of `service`, `date`, and `name` appears more than once.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT service, date, name
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY service, date, name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.service = t2.service AND
       t1.date    = t2.date    AND
       t1.name    = t2.name
```

Comment: I think that did the trick; thank you the help is very much appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple task for a Windowed Aggregate:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY service, date, name) > 1
```

This counts the number of rows with the same combination of values (like Tim Biegeleisen's Derived Table) but unlike a Standard Aggregate it keeps all rows. The `QUALIFY` is a nice Teradata syntax extension to avoid a Derived Table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode values in your query unless you absolutely have to. Instead, take the query you already wrote and join to that.

```
SELECT dupes.*
FROM (your query) yourquery
JOIN table dupes
  ON yourquery.service = dupes.service
 AND yourquery.date = dupes.date
 AND yourquery.name = dupes.name
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the fields present in the table (of the duplicate record), we just execute a query like this (for mysql only):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableName
GROUP BY columName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Well, this is not working in Teradata or any other DBMS besides MySQL using a deprecated feature.